# tailwind class content does not render in nested Lerna packages

Tags: nuxt.js, tailwind-css, lerna

I need some help to improve my design-system project.
so I added Lerna for management multi-app in nuxt also use @nuxtjs/tailwindcss.
in Lerna config and nuxt config everything is ok but when use tailwind CSS for my component design class content doesn't know tailwind
although tailwind CSS works fine.

[my directory,](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/14367811/148964496-0141b608-9abd-4804-a2c0-f9b1bb273c07.png)
[my loaded component](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/14367811/148964741-a95247b6-d6d5-4180-aafb-e965f8970e22.png)
[and result](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/14367811/148964888-d4933aad-27ee-4b4b-bc8b-3d09c00ea247.png)

in the last image, you can see **doesn't load class tailwind**.

thank you for your time.

in my component

```html
    <div class='flex'>
        flex not render in classes list
    </div>
```

```js
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^4.2.1"
```

Comment: Tailwind needs to scan the text `flex` in your code. Please point to the file that has the classes you expect to see on your element.

Comment: how I should do that? @Shreshth

Comment: I find some important notes when disabled ```mode:'jit'``` in nuxt config tailwind everything works fine.

Comment: @DavodAslaniFakor but why is this happening? JIT helps a lot when building the project, and believe me, there are a lot of builds during the day! :)

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue?